# Realm.io - Compound primary key in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, primary-key, realm

I'm struggling to find a way of combining multiple properties into a primary key, using Realm.io and Objective-c.

Take this object as an example:

```
@interface Beacon : RLMObject

@property NSString *uuid;
@property int major;
@property int minor;

@end

RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Beacon)
```

How would I then combine e.g. uuid, major, and minor into a single primary key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an Objective-C solution. It makes use of the fact that only `ignoredProperties` can be overridden. It's a bit more verbose than the Swift version, however, it works, so if you need a compound key in ObjC, this is likely your best bet. One likely limitation is that KVO for the public properties won't work, however, since Realm expects primary keys to remain constant after the object is added to a Realm, this limitation is likely minor. If you did want KVO, you could likely get around it by registering the dependent keys as described [in this document from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002179-BAJEAIEE).

In CompositeKeyObject.h:

```
@interface CompositeKeyObject : RLMObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* partOne;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* partTwo;

@end
```

In CompositeKeyObject.m:

```
@interface CompositeKeyObject ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* partOneValue;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* partTwoValue;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* compositeKey;

@end

@implementation CompositeKeyObject

- (instancetype)initWithValue:(id)value
{
    // Need to make a copy and set the correct "value" properties.
    // Otherwise, the object won't be created properly. 
    NSMutableDictionary* valueCopy = [value mutableCopy];
    if(valueCopy[@"partOne"] != nil) {
        valueCopy[@"partOneValue"] = valueCopy[@"partOne"];
    }
    if(valueCopy[@"partTwo"] != nil) {
        valueCopy[@"partTwoValue"] = valueCopy[@"partTwo"];
    }

    self = [super initWithValue:[valueCopy copy]];
    if(self != nil) {
        // Make sure primary key is in sync.
        [self updatePrimaryKey];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setPartOne:(NSString *)partOne
{
    self.partOneValue = partOne;
    [self updatePrimaryKey];
}

- (void)setPartTwo:(NSString *)partTwo
{
    self.partTwoValue = partTwo;
    [self updatePrimaryKey];
}

- (NSString*)partOne
{
    return self.partOneValue;
}

- (NSString*)partTwo
{
    return self.partTwoValue;
}

- (void)updatePrimaryKey
{
    self.compositeKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ <><><> %@", self.partOne, self.partTwo];
}

+ (NSString *)primaryKey
{
    return @"compositeKey";
}

+ (RLMResults *)objectsWhere:(NSString *)predicateFormat args:(va_list)args {
    predicateFormat = [predicateFormat stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"partOne" withString:@"partOneValue"];
    predicateFormat = [predicateFormat stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"partTwo" withString:@"partTwoValue"];
    return [self objectsWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateFormat arguments:args]];
}

+ (RLMResults *)objectsInRealm:(RLMRealm *)realm where:(NSString *)predicateFormat args:(va_list)args {
    predicateFormat = [predicateFormat stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"partOne" withString:@"partOneValue"];
    predicateFormat = [predicateFormat stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"partTwo" withString:@"partTwoValue"];
    return [self objectsInRealm:realm withPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateFormat arguments:args]];
}

@end
```

And a unit tests:

```
- (void)testCompositeObject
{
    CompositeKeyObject* object = [[CompositeKeyObject alloc] init];
    object.partOne = @"ONE";
    object.partTwo = @"TWO";

    RLMRealm* realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
    [realm transactionWithBlock:^{
        [realm addObject:object];
    }];

    XCTAssertNotNil([CompositeKeyObject objectForPrimaryKey:@"ONE <><><> TWO"]);

    object = [[CompositeKeyObject alloc] init];
    object.partOne = @"ONE";
    object.partTwo = @"TWO";

    [realm transactionWithBlock:^{
        XCTAssertThrows([realm addObject:object]);
    }];
}

- (void)testCompositeObject2
{
    CompositeKeyObject* object = [[CompositeKeyObject alloc] initWithValue:@{@"partOne": @"ONE", @"partTwo": @"TWO"}];

    RLMRealm* realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
    [realm transactionWithBlock:^{
        [realm addObject:object];
    }];

    XCTAssertNotNil([CompositeKeyObject objectForPrimaryKey:@"ONE <><><> TWO"]);
    object = [[CompositeKeyObject alloc] initWithValue:@{@"partOne": @"ONE", @"partTwo": @"TWO"}];

    [realm transactionWithBlock:^{
        XCTAssertThrows([realm addObject:object]);
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How I've done it in our current project is to add a new property for the compound key, make that the primary key. Then, override the setters for all of your parts of the compound key and call a function that updates the compound key.

My ObjC is weak so I can't provide a reliable example written in that language for you, but here's an example in Swift that may help.

```
class Thing: Object {
    dynamic var part1: String = "" {
        didSet {
            self.updateCompoundKey()
        }
    }
    dynamic var part2: String = "" {
        didSet {
            self.updateCompoundKey()
        }
    }
    dynamic var compoundKey: String = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "compoundKey"
    }

    private func updateCompoundKey() {
        self.compoundKey= "\(self.part1)\(self.part2)"
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I get the idea behind this. However, I've not been able to successfully make an implementation in Objective-C. It seems that there is no standard way of getting around this issue in general, when using Realm?